# jQuery Mobile bind events

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little problem with jquery mobile. always my page is called this function runs.

```
$(document).bind('pagechange', function () { 
  // peforms ajax operations
})
```

The problem is that each time my page is viewed it increases the times my ajax is called... example: if the page is viewed 5 times, next time will peform the same ajax request 6 times.

I'm using asp.Net MVC 4.

[image: Multiple ajax requests]

Full code:

```
@{
    //ViewBag.Title = "Consulta";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMenu.cshtml";
}
<div class="ui-body ui-body-b" id="test">
    (...) some html code (...)
</div>
<script>        
$(document).bind('pagechange', function () {
    $('#info').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    $('#name').keypress(function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            var code = $(this)[0].value;

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Consulta/ObterDadosPulseira',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#info').css('visibility', 'visible');

                    var info = $('#info')[0];

                    $('#info [id=gridCod]').html(data[0].cod);
                    $('#info [id=gridName]').html(data[0].nome);

                },
                complete: function () { },
                error: function () { alert('error!'); }
            });

            $(this)[0].value = '';
        }
    });
    $('#name').focus();                       
});
```

Comment: can you post more complete code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally this happens because you are binding an event handler within another event handler. For instance if you were binding a `pagechange` event handler inside of a `pageshow` event handler.

Also if you want to bind to the page events for a specific page, you can just bind to the `data-role="page"` element:

```
$(document).delegate('#my-page-id', 'pageshow', function () {
    //now `this` refers to the `#my-page-id` element
});
```

### Update

I just saw your updated answer with the extra code, and your problem **is** that you are binding an event handler inside another event handler. Basically each time the `pagechange` event is firing, a new event handler is bound to the `#name` element.

Try this:

```
$(document).delegate('#name', 'keypress', function () {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        var code = this.value;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Consulta/ObterDadosPulseira',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {

                $('#info').css('visibility', 'visible');

                var info = $('#info')[0];

                $('#info [id=gridCod]').html(data[0].cod);
                $('#info [id=gridName]').html(data[0].nome);

            },
            complete: function () { },
            error: function () { alert('error!'); }
        });

        this.value = '';
    }
}).bind('pagechange', function () {
    $('#info').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#name').focus();                       
});
```

This uses event delegation to bind the event handler to the `#name` element, this way the event handler will be bound once for all-time.

Docs for `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate