# Slider on home page not initializing when starting on different page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

The slider on my mobile HOME page will not initialize, *only when loading to a different page*.

You can test this by starting at http://www.nolanknill.com/mobile/projects and navigating to the home page. If you reload the browser on the home page (http://www.nolanknill.com/mobile) the slider gets initialized and works properly.

This is the code I have now, I have also tried .bind(), and a .live()  with no luck. I have used these in place of .ready() since .ready() doesn't work with AJAX requests in jQuery mobile (or something like that)

```
<script>
$("#home").ready(function(){
    slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
});
</script>
```

Anyways, let me know what you think.

Comment: I am going to try this fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470297/jquery-mobile-bind-events

Comment: Since you are using jQuery - is there a reason why you aren't doing `slider = new Swipe($('#slider'));` ?

Comment: No, there was no specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

Noticing in firebug that when I load the http://www.nolanknill.com/mobile/projects page first then nav to the home page that it's missing a reference to a file called Swipe.js. Looks like it's not loading that file correctly.

Comment: trying this now 

I wasn't referencing that file on the projects page, since I was doing the initialization on the homepage only.

this definitely helped, thank you, should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Adding this jQuery into the header of all my pages has made the slider work.

```
    $(document).delegate('#homepage', 'pageshow', function () {
        slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
    });
```